# How to test efficiently for spatial/temporal autocorrelatian in a time series

Tags: r, autocorrelation

I am looking at count data over a period of 31 years and 274 connected plots. I suspect this data to have spatial/temporal autocorrelation and I am looking for a well arranged method for testing this.

So far I used DHARMa to check my model residuals which returned the following message:

> testing for spatial autocorrelation requires unique x,y values - if
> you have several observations per location, either use the
> recalculateResiduals function to aggregate residuals per location, or
> extract the residuals from the fitted object, and plot / test each of
> them independently for spatially repeated subgroups (a typical
> scenario would repeated spatial observation, in which case one could
> plot / test each time step separately for temporal autocorrelation).
> Note that the latter must be done by hand, outside
> testSpatialAutocorrelation

As aggregating is not an option I’ve decided to test each of them independently. The following output is the result of testing a single year for spatial autocorrelation:

```
> Moran.I(spat$Residuals, dists.inv)
$observed
[1] -0.007104585

$expected
[1] -0.003663004

$sd
[1] 0.004742504

$p.value
[1] 0.4680297
```

How can I interpret this output? And what would be a good method of testing every single year in my dataset? I thought about writing a loop which would make things very hard to read.

The same thing applies to testing for temporal autocorrelation. This is one of the 274 plots:

```
> lmtest::dwtest(temp$Residuals ~ 1, order.by = temp$year)

    Durbin-Watson test

data:  temp$Residuals ~ 1
DW = 2.1637, p-value = 0.6775
alternative hypothesis: true autocorrelation is greater than 0
```

Is there a smart method of running multiple tests to quickly identify the affected years/plots?

Also how would I include the strength of the spatial/temporal autocorrelation separately per year or plot in the final model?

Comment: Suggesting some r-spatial reading to assist [spatial temporal autocorrelation](https://rspatial.org/raster/analysis/3-spauto.html), HTH

Comment: Hello Chris, thank you for that link. However, I don't see how this answers my questions? The only thing I can see is that Monte Carlo simulation is the prefered method for testing.